# Is it mandatory to get married in Islam?

Tags: nikah, wajib

Is it mandatory to get married in Islam?

Actually a few years back, I fell in love with a girl. Since I belong to a religious family, I did what our religion asks us to, I told my parents and they approached her parents. As I didn't have much good looks and belong to a poor family, so she refused (the only thing I have is a strong moral character and no body cares about that, or my sound educational background as I am an engineer) after that , my parents tried many times but the outcome was the same

The problem is I now don't want to marry, reasons being I don't want to be degraded again plus I still love the same girl. My parents want to but I don't. So does this make me a non-Muslim according to this Hadeeth

> Nikah is from Sunna. So whosoever turns away from my Sunna, then he
>   is not from me.

?

Comment: Welcome to [islam.se]. Please refrain from using such improper English. Go through [ask] and the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 4):

Our Prophet (pbuh) wanted to show us how much the marriage is important. But you have to mention that no marriage always is better than a bad marriage. It is better you search to find a proper girl to marry. Love is important and also is a two way street not a one way!

Comment: Just to add, its not a sin to not get married but that depends on circumstances. If you want advice from people here, I think you should look for someone else. And I think you do want to marry(as you still have feelings for that girl). Since, the parents of that said girl is hesitant to have a relationship with your family, you can not spend the rest of your life like. Move to some place, change job, change country, change your habits-- you are an engineer, not a vagabond, you have a future that you owe to yourself.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, in order to answer your question in short, you should be aware that it is not a mandatory (wajib) act for people or Muslims to get married. About the hadith that you showed

> Nikah is from sunna, so whosever turns away from my Sunnah, then he is
>   not from me

It doesn't mean that Prophet Muhammad meant it as a wajib act. So it can show the importance of marriage. And note that it doesn't mean you wont be Muslim. As the last important matter you'd better notice that narrating such a hadith from the prophet would demonstrate the importance of getting married that he emphasized it. Therefore you should try to follow his orders or even suggestion in order to being successful in the life. Finally you notice it as the advice of the most perfect person of the world and trust go on.

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to make any relation with foreign girl(s), so if u love a girl, you need to cut this relation or continue it and ask her for marriage, Marriage itself can be Wajib if you think you will fall in Haram like Zina and you still can marry.

Sunna if you just can marry and you think you don't really need marry and you don't have specific girl on your mind, e.g.: you busy with studying.

Haram, if someone can’t marry for illness stop him from doing his asked rights in family (like impotency) or very poor can’t feed himself and his-wife or so, or have dangerous infectious disease like AIDS.

Finally "In General" Yes, it’s mandatory because it’s related to community, in Islam community must stay young and healthy.

Comment: I'm agree you to some extent. Meanwhile it is a significant point which you mentioned "Marriage itself can be Wajib if you think you will fall in Haram like Zina and you still can marry."

Answer (score 0):

Marriage is **Sunnat** and not Farz so it is not compulsory but it is appreciated.
*I don't have reference but you can find online about it. I heard this hadeeth in a taqreer.*

Comment: Salat is also a sunnah, but we know that it is farz. A sunnah can be a mandatory or optional.

Comment: @goto how can salat be sunnah if it is ordered in the Quran in many verses, if you mean the sunnah prayers than the analogy fails!

Answer (score 0):

What your parents are doing/saying is not right. There are 10 things that make you a kaffir there is no disagreement upon them marriage isn’t mentioned in any of them listen to them speak to them nicely and obey them but they can't force you into marriage.

*Not getting married means that you are doing something that most likely would lead you to haram if it does marriage is fard.*

Answer (score -1):

About marriage in Islam

Every religion has two parts - one that was revealed by Allah, the great, and other part is what the prophet of the time did himself and said to his followers to do it. The purpose of making one of the people prophet was to present a live model so that the people understand the commands of Allah, the great, perfectly.
So, Marriage is one the most important act in Islam. All the Sahaba kiram were married. Marriage is not explicitly commanded in the Holly Quran. But it is implicitly commanded in the verses in which Allah, the great, says follow me and follow my prophet.

Marriage is the second part of Islam. Now imagine a Muslim who does not follow such a vital Sunnah of his prophet, Muhammad, PBUH. How will a healthy Muslim male and female protect himself/herself from shaitan. And what about the procreation of Muslims. In Islam nothing was less important, everything was and still is very important.

Both parts - revelation from the God and presentation by the Prophet- makes good Muslim.

Saifullah Jan