# Is it necessary for a woman to marry?

Tags: sharia, practical-islam, source-identification

Is it necessary for a woman to marry once in her life? is there any punishment for her if she doesn't marry anyone?

**Question:**

I heard from some one that it is asked not to offer that woman's funeral who doesn't marry any man. is it true?

Comment: http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/10693/11938  ..http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/12034/11938... http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/20178/11938... http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/23322/11938... http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/1167/11938

Answer (score 3):

> I heard from some one that it is asked not to offer that woman's
>   funeral who doesn't marry any man.

I personally never heard of this, it might be a cultural thing not a religious one.

However, with respect to marriage - Islam encourages all to marry especially if it will [prevent sin](http://quran.com/4:25):

> So marry them with the permission of their people and give them their
>   due compensation according to what is acceptable. [They should be]
>   chaste, neither [of] those who commit unlawful intercourse randomly
>   nor those who take [secret] lovers. But once they are sheltered in
>   marriage, if they should commit adultery, then for them is half the
>   punishment for free [unmarried] women. **This [allowance] is for him
>   among you who fears sin, but to be patient is better for you.** And
>   Allah is Forgiving and Merciful.

There is no punishment for you if you are unmarried but otherwise chaste, however as having sexual desires is a natural part of life, it is encouraged for you to marry lest you fall into sin.  Since marriage is made easy in Islam, it is not difficult to expect people to get married.

Keep in mind that family and extending the Islamic faith through progeny is encouraged.

And Allah Knows Best.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head I remember the story of Maryam; the Quran doesn't tell anything about
her marriage status. She is the only female prophet that is mentioned in Quran who guarded her chastity ([66/12](http://quran.com/66/12)) and lived to only serve Allah. I think this shows us that Islam gives us the possibilty to live as a single Muslim as long as we guard our own chastity

Comment: Maryam was not a prophet.